# Ubuntu pip cannot install modules

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, server

Hello guys ive been facing a problem with my ubuntu server.

Sooo i installed mysql-server and things like that so i can create database.

Then I installed python and pip, flask installation went correctly and when im trying to install it again it says requirement already satisfied so thats cool

BUT

When im trying to install mysql-connector or mysql-connecto-python installaion is looping you cann see it [image: HERE]

I can install mysql-connector as many times as i want and it doesnt install.

What can I do in this situation? Anybody was facing this kind of problem?

Comment: That is weird.  Can you share your python and pip versions?

Comment: Got it haha, i had python 2.7 installed :/ Thank you for help!!

Comment: Can you share complete command line given?, and can you try adding `debug` to this command line, and see if that results in a great hint about the failure.

Comment: When you say you installed python... a python comes with ubuntu. Is this a different one?  When dealing with bundled products like the .deb installed python, you are better off getting packages from ubuntu than pip when possible. If you have more than one python installed, something like `python3 -m pip install mymodule` is more likely to install packages to the right place.